# SQL A simple way to select items from the larger category

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with items that can be grouped into two categories. How do I select items from the larger category? For example, if my table looks like

```
| ItemID | ItemProperty | 
|  1     |     true     | 
|  2     |     true     | 
|  3     |    false     | 
|  4     |    false     | 
|  5     |    false     | 
|  6     |     true     | 
|  7     |     true     |
```

then the result should look like

```
| ItemID |
|  1     |
|  2     |
|  6     |
|  7     |
```

This feels like something very simple, and yet I haven't been able to find the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmmm.  Something like this:

```
select t.ItemId
from t join
     (select ItemProperty
      from t
      group by ItemProperty
      order by count(*) desc
      limit 1
     ) tt
     on t.ItemProperty = tt.ItemProperty;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select itemId
From table_name
Where itemProperty = 'true'